# USB port not recognising mouse on first bootup

Tags: windows-xp, usb, mouse, power

On a computer here when first powered on the USB wired mouse is not recognised. The light under the mouse is not lit up. Other usb hub's and keyboards work fine. Disconnecting it and reconnecting it fixes the issue, even after a restart - after the pc is switched off for a length of time (for example overnight) the problem reappears.

I swapped the mouse, updated the bios and installed updated intellimouse drivers, turned of power saving on the usb ports. Any ideas?

edit: bubu, the following descriptioni is correct:

> let me see if i am getting your
>   question correctly. is it that when
>   your mouse is plugged in correctly,
>   and you boot up then it doesn't work
>   when your windows finish booting, even
>   after waiting 3-5 minutes? and then,
>   by that time, if you unplug the mouse
>   and plug it in again then it works. am
>   i getting it correctly? – bubu 4 hours
>   ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: I used a usb to ps2 converter to attach the usb mouse into the ps2 port and have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

i also encountered this problem several time, though more with keyboards.

you may want to try:

(1) Check the setting in BIOS. Sometimes the support for keyboard/mouse was turned off (rather unlikely in your case)
(2) directly connecting the mouse wire to the motherboard USB ports as sometimes the USB hubs may be problematic
(3) see if other mouse works fine, if so, maybe mouse problem

Comment: other mouse has the same problem (which is why i bought new one), i'm directly connecting to usb hubs (tried front and back usb ports)

Comment: let me see if i am getting your question correctly. is it that when your mouse is plugged in correctly, and you boot up then it doesn't work when your windows finish booting, even after waiting 3-5 minutes?

and then, by that time, if you unplug the mouse and plug it in again then it works. am i getting it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like competing drivers. Take a look through your Add/Remove Programs list to see if there are any old mouse driver packages installed.  Remove them all and see if that changes anything.  If not, reinstall the latest version of the drivers.  Still no help?  Download USBDeview from Nirsoft: http://www.nirsoft.net/.  Run it right after poweron/reboot.  Does it show the mouse as connected?  Unplug the mouse and see what changes in USBDeview.  Check all the properties shown for the device in USBDeview to see if there's anything weird.