# How do I prevent my mouse from losing power after cold boot?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

## Problem Description

This problem started for me after upgrading my hardware and re-installing Windows 7 Professional.

After starting the computer, when Windows 7 Professional gets to the log-in prompt, the mouse loses power.

## Hardware

Because I stated that this happened after upgrading my hardware and re-installing Windows 7 Professional, I'll list
    the hardware devices that I believe may be relevant here along with their driver versions taken from the Device
    Manager.

- Motherboard: ASUS Sabertooth Z77

  ### Related Drivers

  - #### Universal Serial Bus Controllers

    - ASMedia XHCI Controller

      - Driver Version 1.14.3.0
    - Generic USB Hub

      - Driver Version 6.1.7601.17586
    - Generic USB Hub

      - Driver Version 6.1.7601.17586
    - Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E26

      - Driver Version 9.3.0.1011
    - Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E2D

      - Driver Version 9.3.0.1011
    - Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller

      - Driver Version 1.0.5.235
    - Intel(R) USB 3.0 Root Hub

      - Driver Version 1.0.5.235
    - USB Composite Device

      - Driver Version 6.1.7601.17586
    - USB Root Hub

      - Driver Version 6.1.7601.17586
    - USB Root Hub

      - Driver Version 6.1.7601.17586
    - USB Root Hub

      - Driver Version 1.14.3.0
- Mouse: Razer SWTOR Gaming Mouse

  ### Related Drivers

  - #### Mice and other pointing devices

    - SWTOR Gaming Mouse by Razer

      - Driver Version 6.2.9200.16384

## Software

Here I will list the software that I believe may be relevant to my problem.

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Service Pack 1
- Razer Synapse 2.0 Configurator

  - Oddly enough, the version listed in Programs and Features is **1.7.15**, perhaps not
                    related to the 2.0 in the product's title.

## Troubleshooting Steps Attempted

- Razer has a FAQ entry that sounds like the exact problem I've been experiencing [Sometimes my Razer product does not work at startup after a cold start?](http://help.razersupport.com/us-en/resolution.asp?sid=100509130206099057133157&pid=400001086&pnm=Razer+SWTOR+Gaming+Mouse&seid=400002913&pos=Windows&top=Troubleshooting&rid=21491).
          I've tried to follow the troubleshooting
          steps as closely as possible, though I don't believe they were written for Windows 7 because I do not have a
          'Hibernation Tab' in the 'Power Options' section of the control panel. All other steps have been completed as
          listed in this FAQ.
- USB selective suspend setting.

  - I found this option when browsing the 'Advanced settings' of the 'Power Options' page in the control
                    panel under USB settings -> USB selective suspend setting. I have set it to 'Setting: Disabled'.

## Workaround

Unplugging the mouse, waiting a couple seconds, and plugging it back in seems to be working for now. However, this is
    an inconvenience that I would like to resolve, as it must be done after every cold start.

Comment: Those instructions were written against Windows 7. You don't have the `Hibernation Tab` because you likely disabled Hibernation on your system. Even if you didn't there is a command you can run to disable it ( well documented on this website ).  Have you tried just using a different USB port by chance?

Comment: If your plugging it into the front of your computer, you may want to try plugging it into the back (direct i/o access to motherboard). Front also goes through motherboard but may not be prioritized.

Comment: I am plugging the mouse into one of the rear USB ports. I will try to cold boot it from a different USB port tonight and see if that resolve the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the clarification on why I don't have the hibernation tab.

Comment: @bwood - Have you thought about opening up a support ticket with `Razer` and request perhaps a RMA I still suspect the drivers are the cause.  Does this problem exist even if there are no drivers installed for the mouse?  I would try just getting rid of `Synapse 2.0` for the time being.

Comment: @Ramhound I have been using Synapse 2.0 because I enjoy the macro features, but that is a good idea. I'll uninstall when I get home and see if that resolves my problem. If that does not work I will contact Razer support and/or request an RMA from them. It'll be another 8 hours or so before I can check but I will update this question with the results.

Comment: @bwood - The reason for getting rid of the `Synapse` software is to confirm if this is a driver problem. Once we get it working we can worry about getting it back installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Using your advice I uninstalled Razer Synapse 2.0, downloaded a new installer from [Razer Support](http://dl.razerzone.com/drivers/Synapse2/win/Razer_Synapse2_v1.07.15.exe), installed using the new installer, logged into Razer Synapse, allowed Razer Synapse to update, and restarted the computer when prompted. After the reboot, the mouse continued to have power after logging into Windows. I then tested by shutting down the computer and leaving the computer off for 30 seconds. After turning the computer back on and logging into Windows the mouse still had power. Thank you!

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, after starting my computer this morning, the problem is back. Either my 30 seconds off test did not work, or something changed that I didn't catch after the 3rd reboot (2nd cold boot).

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Same thing happens with my Razer Deathstalker keyboard... Should've stuck with Logitech, I'm never buying Razer again.

Answer (score 0):

Verify power settings for USB in bios. Also un-check the box in device manager shown below.

[image: Make sure USB power settings are desirable]

Perhaps try removing all but the Razer mouse. There's also BIOS settings related to USB power - I would check in there. Also this problem is related: [USB port not recognising mouse on first bootup](https://superuser.com/q/149464/160458) - one user suggests the workaround of using a PS/2 to USB converter.

Ramhound's comments are related to a competing driver issue also mentioned on that page.

Comment: I've verified the boxes are all unchecked on each USB Root Hub as part of the Razer provided troubleshooting steps. Unfortunately, this has not resolved my problem.

Comment: Is there a service required for the mouse or Razer software that when run, would initialize the mouse? There may be a way to set a task that re-checks/re-initializes ports on boot - more of another workaround that requires less intervention. What hardware changed?

Comment: This was pretty much a fresh build, so almost every piece of hardware changed, and Windows 7 was re-installed.

Comment: How many USB devices do you have plugged in? Perhaps try removing all but the Razer mouse. There's also BIOS settings related to USB power - I would check in there. Also this problem is related: http://superuser.com/q/149464/160458 - one user suggests the workaround of using a PS/2 to USB converter.